# Contest Solution: Remorseful Sam

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, morse-code

> **The Problem**
>
> Sam Morose served for many years as communications officer aboard the U.S.S. Dahdit, a U.S. Coast Guard frigate
>   deployed in the South Pacific. Sam never quite got over the 1995 decision to abandon Morse code as the primary ship-to
>   shore
>   communication scheme, and was forced to retire soon after because of the undue mental anguish that it was causing.
>   After leaving the Coast Guard, Sam landed a job at the local post office, and became a model U.S. Postal worker…
>   That said, it isn’t surprising that Sam is now holding President Clinton hostage in a McDonald’s just outside the
>   beltway. The FBI and Secret Service have been trying to bargain with Sam for the release of the president, but they find it
>   very difficult since Sam refuses to communicate in anything other than Morse code. Janet Reno has just called you to write a
>   program that will interpret Sam’s demands in Morse code as English.
>   Morse code represents characters of an alphabet as sequences of dits (short key closures) and dahs (longer key
>   closures). If we let a period (.) represent a dit and a dash (-) represent a dah, then the Morse code version of the English
>   alphabet is:
>
> [image: morse table]
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> Your program must takes its input from the ASCII text file `morse.in`. The file contains periods and dashes representing
>   a message composed only of the English alphabet as specified above. One blank space is used to separate letters and three
>   blanks are used to separate words. Sample contents of the file could appear as follows:
>
> ```
> .... . .-.. .-.. ---   -- -.--   -. .- -- .   .. ...   ... .- --
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> Your program must direct its output to the screen and must be the English interpretation of the Morse code found in the
>   input file. There must be no blanks between letters in the output and only one blank between words. You must use all
>   capital letters in the output. The output corresponding to the input file above is:
>
> ```
> HELLO MY NAME IS SAM
> ```

**code.py**

```
import re

codes = {
    '.-':'A',
    '-...':'B',
    '-.-.':'C',
    '-..':'D',
    '.':'E',
    '..-.':'F',
    '--.':'G',
    '....':'H',
    '..':'I',
    '.---':'J',
    '-.-':'K',
    '.-..':'L',
    '--':'M',
    '-.':'N',
    '---':'O',
    '...':'S',
    '-':'T',
    '..-':'U',
    '...-':'V',
    '.--':'W',
    '-..-':'X',
    '-.--':'Y',
    '--..':'Z'
}

with open('morse.in') as f:
    for line in f:
        t = []
        for s in line.strip().split(' '):
            t.append(codes.get(s) if s else ' ')
        print(re.sub(' +', ' ', ''.join(t)))
```

Any advice on performance enhancement and solution simplification is appreciated, as are topical comments!

Comment: I always wondered why jslint dislikes single quotes, now I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are using [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to handle the spaces, you may as well use it to perform the entire task.  Note that I've added entries to `codes` that maps triple-space to a space, and space to nothing.  Also, since `codes` contains one entry per line, I prefer to put a comma after every entry, including a superfluous comma after the last one, to make it easy to add or remove entries.

```
import re

codes = {
    '.-': 'A',
    '-...': 'B',
    '-.-.': 'C',
    …
    '--..': 'Z',
    '   ': ' ',
    ' ': '',
}

with open('morse.in') as f:
    print(
        re.sub(
            '[.-]+|   | ',
            lambda match: codes[match.group()],
            f.read()
        ),
        end=''
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is just puzzle code, but treating this as a merge request for a production system:

1. Replacing unknown codes with a space character seems counter to requirements. I would instead just `t.append(codes[s])` and let the script exit with an error when given invalid input. If I wanted a more user friendly error message I'd catch this specific error and either print a warning on standard error before continuing or throw an application-specific error.
2. You would also want to read from standard input rather than a specific file. That way you could use your script as part of a pipeline.
3. Translation should be separate from reading input. That way the translation code can be reused independently of the input method.
4. If you may have huge input I would use buffered reads rather than line-based. The former doesn't have to inspect every character, and the user can't kill the program by passing in a single long line.
5. The mapping from a string of three spaces to a single space should be in `codes`. That way you're operating exactly to spec rather than second guessing what other sequences of spaces mean, and it gets rid of a costly regex replacement.